# calculating the total hours users are looged-in for date range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sklearn-pandas

I have my data about users' event logs in unix timestamp as follows:

```
data = {'id': [533815001,533815001,533815001,533815001,533815001,533815001,
              533815003,533815003,533815003,533815003,533815003,533815003],
 'start_time': [1459181400, 1459182480, 1459185780,1459494634,1459496914,1459498354,
                1459837648, 1459838908, 1459840108,1461578728,1461579508,1461581428,]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

        id      start_time
0   533815001   1459181400
1   533815001   1459182480
2   533815001   1459185780
3   533815001   1459494634
4   533815001   1459496914
5   533815001   1459498354
6   533815003   1459837648
7   533815003   1459838908
8   533815003   1459840108
9   533815003   1461578728
10  533815003   1461579508
11  533815003   1461581428
```

And I want to know total number of hours users are active in a range of date. So I add `datetime` column from `start_time`, like so:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.start_time, unit='s')
df
id  start_time  date
0   533815001   1459181400  2016-03-28 16:10:00
1   533815001   1459182480  2016-03-28 16:28:00
2   533815001   1459185780  2016-03-28 17:23:00
3   533815001   1459494634  2016-04-01 07:10:34
4   533815001   1459496914  2016-04-01 07:48:34
5   533815001   1459498354  2016-04-01 08:12:34
6   533815003   1459837648  2016-04-05 06:27:28
7   533815003   1459838908  2016-04-05 06:48:28
8   533815003   1459840108  2016-04-05 07:08:28
9   533815003   1461578728  2016-04-25 10:05:28
10  533815003   1461579508  2016-04-25 10:18:28
11  533815003   1461581428  2016-04-25 10:50:28
```

As can be seen, user `533815001` was active on `2016-03-28` at `16h10` all through `17h23` (1-hour 13 minutes). Also on `2016-04-01` at `07h10` through `08h12` (1 hour 2-minutes).

Similarly user `533815003`  was logged in on `2016-4-05` at `06h27` through `07h08` (41 minutes), and on `2016-4-25` at `10h05` all through  `10h50` (45 minutes).

- If I want to know number of hours users are spent before `2016-3-31`, that would be `1.13minutes` (only user `533815001` was active).
- Total hours user was active until `2016-4-02` would then be `1h-13min + 41min = 1h.54minutes`.
- Between `2016-4-1` and `2016-4-10` would be `1h02mins + 41mins = 1h43mins`.
- and so on...

How do I do this kind of analysis?

Comment: How do you decide that a date is still part of a range? What if there were one entry at 22h on 2016-03-28 for the first user? Would it extend the previous range? Is there a threshold? Can a range span 2 days?

Comment: @mozway The actual data was collected between March and May 2026. I give a MWE for illustration but the original dataset was users' GPS traces logged at `1 second` sampling rate, In that case, for the first user for example, I consider an interval of `30minutes` to mean different activity by that user, which is fair for the use case.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to do on user and date level. For that I suggest having a `date` column as well:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.start_time, unit='s')
df['date'] = df['datetime'].apply(lambda x: str(x).split(' ')[0])
```

|  | id | start_time | datetime | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 533815001 | 1459181400 | 2016-03-28 16:10:00 | 2016-03-28 |
| 1 | 533815001 | 1459182480 | 2016-03-28 16:28:00 | 2016-03-28 |
| 2 | 533815001 | 1459185780 | 2016-03-28 17:23:00 | 2016-03-28 |
| 3 | 533815001 | 1459494634 | 2016-04-01 07:10:34 | 2016-04-01 |
| 4 | 533815001 | 1459496914 | 2016-04-01 07:48:34 | 2016-04-01 |
| 5 | 533815001 | 1459498354 | 2016-04-01 08:12:34 | 2016-04-01 |
| 6 | 533815003 | 1459837648 | 2016-04-05 06:27:28 | 2016-04-05 |
| 7 | 533815003 | 1459838908 | 2016-04-05 06:48:28 | 2016-04-05 |
| 8 | 533815003 | 1459840108 | 2016-04-05 07:08:28 | 2016-04-05 |
| 9 | 533815003 | 1461578728 | 2016-04-25 10:05:28 | 2016-04-25 |
| 10 | 533815003 | 1461579508 | 2016-04-25 10:18:28 | 2016-04-25 |
| 11 | 533815003 | 1461581428 | 2016-04-25 10:50:28 | 2016-04-25 |

Now you can groupby them to have both min and max on each day for each user:

```
dfx = df.groupby(['id', 'date']).agg({'datetime':['min', 'max']}).reset_index()
dfx['duration'] = dfx['datetime']['max'] - dfx['datetime']['min']
dfx
```

|  | ('id', '') | ('date', '') | ('datetime', 'min') | ('datetime', 'max') | ('duration', '') |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 533815001 | 2016-03-28 | 2016-03-28 16:10:00 | 2016-03-28 17:23:00 | 0 days 01:13:00 |
| 1 | 533815001 | 2016-04-01 | 2016-04-01 07:10:34 | 2016-04-01 08:12:34 | 0 days 01:02:00 |
| 2 | 533815003 | 2016-04-05 | 2016-04-05 06:27:28 | 2016-04-05 07:08:28 | 0 days 00:41:00 |
| 3 | 533815003 | 2016-04-25 | 2016-04-25 10:05:28 | 2016-04-25 10:50:28 | 0 days 00:45:00 |

Now you can have this duration aggregated as well if you want:

```
dfx.groupby('id').agg({('duration', ''): sum})
```

| id | ('duration', '') |
| --- | --- |
| 533815001 | 0 days 02:15:00 |
| 533815003 | 0 days 01:26:00 |

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use `groupby` with a custom `Grouper` then keep the min and the max entries for a day and compute the difference:

```
out = (df.groupby(['id', pd.Grouper(freq='D', key='date')])['date']
         .agg(['min', 'max']).diff(axis=1)['max']
         .rename('active_time').reset_index())
print(out)

# Output
          id       date     active_time
0  533815001 2016-03-28 0 days 01:13:00
1  533815001 2016-04-01 0 days 01:02:00
2  533815003 2016-04-05 0 days 00:41:00
3  533815003 2016-04-25 0 days 00:45:00
```